# Parsing ISO 8601 dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, iso8601

This might sound simple, but I am having a really difficult time to find a solution to.. I have a simple ajax call that returns a JSON object:

```
{"d":"{\"fID\":57,\"headerPhotoPath\":\"img/image.jpg\",\"CreatedDate\":\"2013-05-16T10:18:10.183\",\"UpdatedDate\":\"2013-05-20T09:26:26.18\",\"isActive\":true,\"isVisible\":true,\"ContentsOrderedBy\":\"NewsUpdatedDateDesc\",\"FolderName\":\"Kemal\u0027s File\",\"FolderDescription\":\"folderdesc\",\"ReadCount\":0,\"ContentCount\":3}"}
```

As you can see the dates are returned are in ISO 8601 which is output in the format of `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.s`

I retreive this JSON via jQuery as follows; ( I am omitting the obvious for the sake of simplicity)

```
success: function (msg) {
var fd = JSON.parse(msg.d);
    $('#img').attr('src', '../' + fd.headerPhotoPath)
    $('#fDesc').html(fd.FolderDescription);
    $('#fCreated').html(fd.CreatedDate);
    $('#fUpdated').html(fd.UpdatedDate);
    $('#fIsActive').html(convertTrueFalse(fd.isActive));
    $('#fIsVisible').html(convertTrueFalse(fd.isVisible));
    $('#fReadCount').html(fd.ReadCount);
}
```

How can I parse my already parsed JSON object to output dates in the formats of "dd/MM/yyyy" or in any other correctly readable format for that matter?

Comment: Not a solution but an alternative: http://www.datejs.com/ - and the decimals on the seconds aren't valid ISO8601 I think.

Comment: You may give a look at momentjs, a very handy library for parsing anf manipulating dates http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score -1):

It seems [Colin Snover (csnover)](http://github.com/csnover) on GitHub has created a function that will parse the iso8601 dates for you. Have a look at [this function](http://github.com/csnover/js-iso8601/blob/master/iso8601.js) within the [js-iso8601](http://github.com/csnover/js-iso8601) repository.

From there, the function will return a [javascript date object](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), which you can write out in any format you like using the `date()` function.